# Is there a way to automatically detect if a variable is multiple categorical or continuous

Tags: algorithm, variables, continuous

If your dataset is big, say you have thousands of variables. Some variables are multiple categorical and some are continuous. Question is, how do you know if a variable is continuous vs multiple categorical (say 50 categories)? Is there any algorithm that can classify this?

Comment: Can you give an example of your case?

Comment: I'm working on a massive survey data on HIV. The surveys ask people very different questions on occupation, lifestyle, etc. Some variables have over 30 categories, say occupation, how many times they have sex etc. The way that previous researchers do is to read the metadata, identify whether it is categorical or numerical. However, as the variables are growing, we are thinking if there's a way to automatically classify variable types, instead of having a person making a decision each time.

Comment: I guess this involves statistics/machine learning. You should better ask here https://stats.stackexchange.com :)